# Let me out or let me through?

Tags: word-choice

What should i say to a person sitting next to me (in a bus or a plane), if I need him to let me out? Let me out, please or let me through, please?

Answer (score 1):

Both are fine.

I would add an "Excuse me," and a "Could you..."?

·Excuse me could you let me out?

·Excuse me could you let me through?